# Android setReadAccess for Parse ADMIN error

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I use a Parse database. I would like to have access for simple users and an admin user. The would be that each user could see only his/her own data but the admin user could see all of users' data.

I create a ParseUser, and if the current user is equal with it, it should be known it is the admin user.
I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id

I think the mistakes are with if function (never become true) and this: acl.setReadAccess(ADMIN,true);

Could anyone suggest something?

```
ParseUser ADMIN = new ParseUser();
ADMIN.setUsername("ADMIN3");
ADMIN.setPassword("a");

// Create a post.
   AnywallPost post = new AnywallPost();

   // Set the location to the current user's location
   post.setLocation(geoPoint);
   post.setText(text);
   post.setUser(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

   ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();


   // Give read accesses
  if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == ADMIN) {
      acl.setReadAccess(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), true);
  }
  else
  {
      acl.setReadAccess(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(),true);
      acl.setReadAccess(ADMIN,true);
  }
   post.setACL(acl);



   // Save the post
   post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseException e) {
           dialog.dismiss();
           finish();
       }
   });
```

Comment: You need to make an AdminUser that extends ParseUser. You also need to make a NormalUser that extends ParseUser. As for the nullpointer I think that you need to signup that user before querying read access. From a bigger perspective, what youre trying to do actually take way more logic than just setting read access via the ACL. I would just make an attribute for the AdminUser that allows then to query data from everyone, if that attribute flags true, then your queryadapter will adapt for that specific admin. I hope this makes sense. Please ask questions, Parse is great and I like helping.

Comment: Thank you. I will do this changes. I hope these suggestions will help.

Comment: Could you suggest me how to implement making attribute for the AdminUser? And how the code of flag would be? It makes sense but I don't have a clue how to do it, although I looked for it for a long time via Internet.